# Is it possible to use openssl API's to create certificate buffer that is compatible with Windows crypto API's?

Tags: cryptography, openssl

We use the following openssl API to retrieve the certificate from personal information exchange file

```
ret = PKCS12_parse ( p12, "mqroot", &pkey, &cert, &ca );
        if ( 0 == ret )
        {
            printf ( "\tError: PKCS12_parse %d\n", GetLastError( ) );
            hResult = GetLastError ( );
            __leave;
        }// if
```

Can this certificate be converted to any data type that is compatible with windows CAPI.

```
hCertStore = PFXImportCertStore( &data, wszPassword, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE | CRYPT_USER_KEYSET );
        if ( !hCertStore )
        {
            hResult = GetLastError();
            __leave;
        } // if
pUsrCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(
            hCertStore,
            pUsrCertContext );
        if( !pUsrCertContext )
        {
            hResult = GetLastError( );
            __leave;
        } // if
```

Using the above functions we get the encoded certificate data as pUsrCertContext and are there any functions to get encoded certificate data using openssl so that windows API's can be ignored for compatibility in other operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get PEM/DER encoded cert from OpenSSL and use [CryptStringToBinary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380285%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function to convert from PEM/DER to CryptoAPI binary format.

See also the very bottom of this [post](http://pumka.net/2009/12/19/reading-writing-and-converting-rsa-keys-in-pem-der-publickeyblob-and-privatekeyblob-formats/#more-59).